# Allow File Types in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We are migrating our old website into SharePoint. Until the time we get all issues worked out, we want to move the existing website into SharePoint (unchanged if possible). This way the users can start seeing SharePoint. There are some file types not being allowed to be copied (either through SharePoint or Explorer). These file types are not even SharePoint's blocked list. Is there some way we can get these files into SharePoint to host the websites. If we cannot get all files uploaded, we would lose some functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "migrating our old website into SharePoint"? SharePoint is not a website hosting software like Wordpress. It's a collaboration platform, and even though it has elaborate publishing capabilities for public-facing web sites they require thorough implementation. That said, your effort might be completely misleading.

Comment: And in any case, your question is missing important details, like *what* file types you mean *exactly*. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: One file type in particular is .jshintrc. I do not now what the file is used for...just that I am tasked with getting it moved it over. And if I cannot, find out why. Sorry, that is all I know right now. The exact file type is irrelevant which is why I did not include any. I just want to know if you can move over file types that are not specifically denied in SharePoint. Because right now it is not letting me.

Comment: By "migrating...", I mean the customer wants their exact website moved under SharePoint (they heard it can be done). Then they want to be able to access the website even though they type a their new SharePoint URL. I've seen an example (http://mysharepoint.sites/oldwebstructure. I just do not know how it is done yet.

Comment: It is highly likely that the owner of the task you are supposed to perform doesn't know how SharePoint works and what it's good for. Nevertheless, you'd reconfigure it to allow these file types, most likely the results wouldn't work.

Comment: Based on your second comment: **no**, this is **not** how SharePoint works. Your customer is naive to expect an impossible result. Their web site would have to be *completely* re-engineered. Let them know about this conversation.

Comment: Thanks...after other searching, I was starting to suspect it would not work but wanted try one last attempt at finding an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question at all.